# NetLogo permission oddities

Tags: permissions, patch, turtle-graphics, netlogo

I'm having issues with my netlogo program. Code follows:

```
globals[
growth-param
money-size-ratio

]

turtles-own[
  location
  tsize
  bbalance
]

to setup
  ca
  reset-ticks
  ask patches[set pcolor blue]

  create-turtles initial-telemarketers [
    set size 1
    set bbalance 0.0
    setxy random-xcor random-ycor
    set shape "circle"
  ]
  set growth-param 1000
  set money-size-ratio 0.001
end

to go
  ask patches[set pcolor blue]
  sell
  accounting
  observer-updates
  tick
end

to sell

  let territory 10 * sqrt size
  let maxcalls 100 * size
  ask n-of maxcalls patches in-radius territory[
    if pcolor = blue [set pcolor black]
    set bbalance bbalance + 2
  ]

end

to accounting
  let cost size * 50
  ask turtles[
  set bbalance bbalance - cost

  ifelse bbalance < 1
  [die]
  [set size bbalance * growth-param]
  ]

end

to observer-updates

end
```

It's supposed to be a model of how many telemarketing companies interact, simplistically. It's from Railsback & Grimm's modeling book.

Each time it tries to run, it provides two problems that I can see: in procedure sell, it doesn't want to set bbalance to the new value because it is turtle-only, and tick is observer-context only.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1):

```
globals[

  money-size-ratio

]

turtles-own[
  location
  tsize
  bbalance
  maxsize
]

to setup
  ca
  reset-ticks
  ask patches[set pcolor blue]

  create-turtles initial-telemarketers [
    set size 1
    set bbalance 0.0
    setxy random-xcor random-ycor
    set shape "circle"
    set maxsize 0
  ]

  set money-size-ratio 0.001
end

to go

  ask patches[set pcolor blue]
  ask turtles [sell]
  ask turtles [accounting]  ;; let's ask the turtles to do this
  observer-updates
  tick

end

to sell
  let territory 10 * sqrt size
  let maxcalls 100 * size
  if maxcalls > 40401[
    set maxcalls 40401;keeps maxcalls within acceptable bounds
  ]
  let coun 0
  ask n-of maxcalls patches in-radius territory[
    if pcolor = blue[
      set pcolor black
      set coun coun + 2
    ] 
  ]
  set bbalance bbalance + coun


end

to accounting
  let cost size * 50 ;; size is a turtle variable so if you want to access it this way, let's make the whole thing
                     ;;  a turtle procedure.  That's what was confusing Netlogo about the tick command 

    set bbalance bbalance - cost

    if bbalance > growth-param
     [set size size + (bbalance - growth-param) * money-size-ratio
      set bbalance growth-param
       ]
    if size > maxsize[
      set maxsize size
    ]


    if bbalance <= 0
    [show (word "dead. Maximum size: " maxsize)
      die

      ]

    if size = 0
    [show (word "dead. Maximum size: " maxsize)
      die

      ]



end

to observer-updates

end
```

Answer (score 0):

`sell` is a turtle procedure (because it uses turtle primitives such as `size` and `in-radius`).  But `go` is an observer procedure. You can't call a turtle procedure directly from an observer procedure; you need to specify which turtles you want to run it. Inside `go`, I think you may have meant to write `ask turtles [ sell ]` instead of just `sell`.

Comment: Okay, in case anyone tries to google this and can't find anything else, here is my full (working!) code: